# Change Figwheel compile directory with Lein

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

I'm trying to move from lein-figwheel to figwheel-main and I'm using lein.
By default figwheel-main compiles the build and puts it in target/public/cljs-out directory.
However I wanted it to be in a different location resources/public/js/.

I tried adding compile-path and the target-path in my project.clj and nothing is getting changed.

```
:profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.1"]
                                  [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]]
                   :target-path "resources/public/js"
                   :compile-path "resources/public/js"
                   :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}}})
```

I expected the build to get compiled to `resourses/public/js` directory. But still I see that its getting compiled to `target/public/cljs-out` directory. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Two months I switched from the old figwheel on lein to `figwheel-main` using a Clojure Deps build.  The new combination is *much* easier to understand.  I'd suggest migrating your CLJS build over to Clojure Deps.

Answer (score 0):

I use lein-cljsbuild to build ClojureScript along with figwheel. It has `:cljsbuild :output-to` and `:output-dir` parameters that control a directory to output your files to. From [this doc](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Configuration-Options) I assume that this is the right way to compile files.